# Connect Ember 2.3 App to WordPress backend with the version 2 WP REST API using adapters and serializers

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, ember.js

I'm connecting an [Ember 2.3](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0) front-end with a WordPress admin panel for a client. I'm using the version 2 of the [WordPress JSON API](http://v2.wp-api.org/).

The API is great and I've used it before with $AJAX and XHR requests, but never felt that great about my implementation and it was with version 1.

*This time*, I've set up an adapter like this:

*app/adapters/application.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://example.com',
  namespace: 'wp-json/wp/v2'
});
```

JSONAPIAdaper is the new default and expects the returned data to be complient to the [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/) standard.

and then used findAll to GET the data for all of the pages into the store.

*app/routes/application.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    var pagesData = this.store.findAll('page');
    console.log(pagesData);
    return pagesData;
  }

});
```

Here's a URL for an example.
http://mellonwinslowdb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages

What is returned, doesn't appear to be compliant to the jsonapi standard.

> Error while processing route: work Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
>       * One or more of the following keys must be present: "data", "errors", "meta".
>
> Error: Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
>       * One or more of the following keys must be present: "data", "errors", "meta".

This leads me to check out the options to serialize the data into shape. I tried a few of the options but I don't fully understand what is happening and therefor, what to do.

*app/serializers/application.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
});
```

This also receives errors right off the bat, and so I think - well it's not valid jsonapi data... so I'll try the regular JSON serializer.

*app/serializers/application.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
});
```

I'm unsure why, but the errors are gone and I get back an array of the pages.

For example, on the **/about** "view" I'll need to show some content from that json in the store / and I don't want to send another request to a server, so I try out this `peekRecord()` ~ which returns some page data from the store.

*app/routes/about.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    var pageData = this.store.peekRecord('page', 43);
    console.log(pageData);
    return pageData;
  }

});
```

In my template, I try and show some of the data I'll expect:
*app/templates/about.hbs*

```
<h1>About</h1>

{{model.id}}
{{model.title}}
{{model.content}}

{{outlet}}
```

I can get the ID, but when I look further into the console.log of the JSON, it doesn't look how I expect it to - and none of the content I thought would be there, *except the id*, is there...

What adapter / serializer setup can get me where I need to be and grabbing post and page data? I would expect this combo to be prevalent.

Any direction is much appreciated. : )

Comment: Have you read https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/customizing-serializers/ ?

Comment: @locks Yes, I've been following the docs as I try to figure it out.

Comment: @locks I'm reading this too - http://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously too late to help with this project, but for anyone in the future, there is a GitHub repo that contains an example Ember adapter, model, serializer, and templates for interacting with WP REST API [here](https://github.com/oskarrough/ember-wordpress).

Adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import config from 'ember-get-config';

// The WP API requires a rest adapter.
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: config.wordpressHost,
    // This is the default namespace for WP API v2.
    namespace: 'wp-json/wp/v2',

    handleResponse(status, headers, payload, requestData) {
        // Wordpress sends meta data (useful for pagination) in GET requests headers.
        // Here we move it to a `meta` property which Ember expects.
        if (payload) {
            const meta = {
                total: headers['X-WP-Total'],
                totalPages: headers['X-WP-TotalPages']
            };
            payload.meta = meta;
        }
        return this._super(status, headers, payload, requestData);
    }
});
```

Post model: (There is a term model as well)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const {Model, attr, hasMany} = DS;

export default Model.extend({
    title: attr('string'),
    content: attr('string'),
    excerpt: attr('string'),
    slug: attr('string'),
    date: attr('date'),
    featured_media: attr('number'),
    format: attr(),
    categories: hasMany('category', {async: true}),
    tags: hasMany('tag', {async: true}),
    acf: attr()
});
```

Serializer:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    isNewSerializerAPI: true,

    // Here we wrap the payload in a named object after the model type
    // because this is what Ember expects { post: { datahere } }
    normalizeSingleResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        var payloadTemp = {};
        payloadTemp[primaryModelClass.modelName] = [payload];

        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payloadTemp, id, requestType);
    },

    // Then, we can deal with our missing root element when extracting arrays from the JSON.
    normalizeArrayResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        const payloadTemp = {};
        const rootKey = Ember.String.pluralize(primaryModelClass.modelName);

        payloadTemp[rootKey] = payload;

        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payloadTemp, id, requestType);
    },

    normalize(modelClass, resourceHash, prop) {
        // As you get bored typing `title.rendered`, here we move the `rendered` part up.
        if (resourceHash.content && resourceHash.title.rendered) {
            resourceHash.content = resourceHash.content.rendered;
            resourceHash.title = resourceHash.title.rendered;
        }
        if (resourceHash.title && resourceHash.title.rendered) {
            resourceHash.title = resourceHash.title.rendered;
        }
        if (resourceHash.excerpt && resourceHash.excerpt.rendered) {
            resourceHash.excerpt = resourceHash.excerpt.rendered;
        }
        return this._super(modelClass, resourceHash, prop);
    }
});
```

This has helped me a lot, maybe it can help others too.

Comment: Hey @Dalton - posting the actual code from those repos is going to get out-dated quick as the addon evolves! ~ if you just post a link to these two repos: https://github.com/oskarrough/ember-wordpress  and  https://github.com/EmberSherpa/wp-rest-jsonapi-serializer as good options... I'll mark it as the answer. (forgot about this post - but have been implementing it with this addon for quite a while.) Going very well. : )

Comment: Also, if you thought this question was worth your time... that is how you know when you should upvote a question. ; )